# Default path problem in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to create my first BB app. It's going ok but I have a problem. My router looks like this:

```
var PlayersAppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        '': 'index',
    },

    initialize: function () {
        this.model = new PlayersAppModel({});
        this.view = new PlayersAppView({model: this.model});
    },

    index: function () {
        alert('It works'); //<-- It doesn't
    },
});
```

And later in my code I have:

```
$(function () {
        window.app = new PlayersAppRouter;
        Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});

        app.model.players.reset(<?php require('players.php'); ?>); //<-- players.php loads a bunch of JSON data.
});
```

Now, *why doesn't the index action of the router fire?* Am I doing something wrong? Are there any other problems with this code?

The full app can be found here: http://development.zeta-two.com/development/f14/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of your pushState:true at it works

http://fiddle.jshell.net/r5TEk/9/show/

There maybe a bug with pushSate. See here

https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/issues/451

Answer (score 2):

Using a regular expression, add a route manually in the `initialize` function.

```
...
initialize: function() {
    this.route(/\/?/, 'index', this.index);
},
index: function() {
    alert('It works!');
},
...
```

This works fine with `{pushState: true}`.

http://jsfiddle.net/sergio/WpKPP/

http://jsfiddle.net/sergio/WpKPP/show

Comment: This overides other routes. Check out the fiddle with sub url http://jsfiddle.net/sergio/WpKPP/show/search/

Answer (score 0):

Can't remember where I read it, buy I find you have to call `initialize` on the router. This is my working example, fired inside a `jquery.ready` function.

```
MainView = new View.main();
appRouter = new Router();
// set up single page app with push state
Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
appRouter.initialize();
```

Routes config.

```
routes: {
    "": "index"
}
```

Using @serg.io answer `this.route(/\/?/, 'index', this.index);` caused it override my other routes.